# Changing minutes difference in JQuery.ptTimeSelect time picker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pttimeselect

I am working on a scheduler application in asp.net. Here I need to set the time to execute a job. I am working with [jQuery.ptTimeSelect](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html) time picker control to select the time. I have a requirement where user should be able to select the time on per minute basis. For example, if user wants to run the job at 7:13 PM, he must be able to select this time. But the minutes difference coming in this time picker control is 5 minutes. I am looking for the right option to set the minutes difference to 1, instead of 5. I looked for the [documentation](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html) but couldn't find the right option.

Can we change the difference between minutes in ptTimeSelect or should I look for other time picker controls ?

Answer (score 0):

in their code they have all created as a html structure

so instead of this

```
 +    '                    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">'
                        +    '                        <div class="ui-widget-content ptTimeSelectRightPane">'
                        +    '                            <div class="ptTimeSelectMinCntr">'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">00</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">05</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">10</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">15</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">20</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">25</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">30</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">35</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">40</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">45</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">50</a>'
                        +    '                                <a class="ptTimeSelectMin ui-state-default" href="javascript: void(0);">55</a>'
                        +    '                                <br style="clear: left;" /><div></div>'
                        +    '                            </div>'
                        +    '                        </div>'
                        +    '                    </div>'
```

you can generate your values on jQuery document ready to replace those values with yours or just modify their code.

I could add this as a comment but the code was to long.